# Adding effect to Partial renders using jQuery in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, renderpartial

In rails, whenever I render a partial, it just displays with no effect. Is it possible to apply a jQuery effect say a slideDown() whenever a render partial is called in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you mean slideDown() ?

Do you want this to happen after a regular page request or upon rendering an Ajax call?

If it's a regular request you might want to put in your jQuery code in the application.js file.

If it's in upon rendering an ajax call it would then be in the view_name.js.erb file.

Editing to answer comment request for some code sample. So you put this in your view_name.js.erb

```
$("#div-name").replaceWith("thanks for your vote").hide().slideDown(300);
```

So many different things you could do in there

Comment: thanks for the correction.. yes its slideDown(), I edited the question. Its rendering upon an ajax call. Can you please give me a code sample on this ?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. In your partial erb, wrap the content in a div. At the bottom of the partial erb file, after your closing div tag, add a javascript block that calls the slideUp function on that div.

Comment: Could you try posting some of your code? There's no magic wand here.